# How to modify a relative layout to fit a specific left, right, top, bottom position on a screen

Tags: android, canvas, android-relativelayout, draw

My relative layout is named "highlight".

```
public static void selectText(float left, float right, float top, float bottom) {

    highlight.getLayoutParams().width =(int) (right-left);
    highlight.getLayoutParams().height=(int) (bottom - top);
    highlight.setX(left);
    highlight.setY(top);
 }
```

This works great for highlighting text as far as setting the top left corner of the highlight box. But, the box expands all the way to the bottom right corner of the screen, no matter how small I make the .width and .height values.

Answer (score 1):

You set your width and height as wrap_content. Your layout will have the size of it's content.

Instead of:

```
highlight.getLayoutParams().width =(int) (right-left);
highlight.getLayoutParams().height=(int) (bottom - top);
```

Try:

```
highlight.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Check this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the simple 'get layout params' wasn't working. I needed to make a new layout params entirely.

```
int width = (int) (right-left);
int height = (int) (bottom - top);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlMainlayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (right-left), (int) (bottom - top));
highlight.setLayoutParams(rlMainlayoutParams);
highlight.setX(left);
highlight.setY(top);
```

The above answer doesn't answer my question, perhaps because I was not clear that this relative layout doesn't hold any text, it only highlights certain text already present on the screen (in a PDF document, where I cannot necessarily just extract the text to a PDF document).

Answer (score 0):

After you've modified a view's layout params, call `requestLayout()` on the view for the changes to take effect.

(Calling `setLayoutParams()` also implicity calls `requestLayout()`.)

Comment: Thank you. I found another work-around, but this probably would've worked too.